# How to set a colour legend with the days of the week in Plotly bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

i have a graph like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWrSx.png
and i would like to have a legend with the name of the days of week, each of them with their own color
so that every bar in the chart ( which represent a single day) have his respective colour associate with the day of the week.
I hope i have been understendable, thanks a lot to everyone who'll reply.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the source data? (as text in the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do that (with random data):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# generate dummy data 
dates = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-06-30", freq="1d")
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": dates, "val": np.random.randint(0, 100, len(dates))})

# plot it. 
fig = go.Figure()
for day_of_week in range(7):
    sub_df = df[df.date.dt.dayofweek == day_of_week]
    day_name = sub_df.date.dt.day_name().iloc[0]
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=sub_df.date,
        y=sub_df.val,
        name=day_name
    ))
    

fig.show()
```

The output is:
[image]

Comment: If it answers your question, it would be great if you could accept my answer for future generations.

Comment: Nice answer. I upvoted it. I just imported libraries on top of your code.

Answer (score 2):

@Roy2012 answer is perfect and should remain the accepted one. I just would like to add a `plotly.express` version

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# generate dummy data 
dates = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-06-30")
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": dates, "val": np.random.randint(0, 100, len(dates))})

df["dow"] = df["date"].dt.weekday_name

px.bar(df, x="date", y="val", color="dow")
```

[image]

And in case you want your legend go from Monday to Sunday you could add these 2 lines

```py
df["dow"] = df["date"].dt.weekday
df = df.sort_values("dow").reset_index(drop=True)

df["dow"] = df["date"].dt.weekday_name
px.bar(df, x="date", y="val", color="dow")
```

[image]